# Banach spaces $X,Y$ and a mapping $f:X\to Y$

Tags: linear-transformations, banach-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces and a mapping $f\in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$. Suppose that $f$ is also an injective map and an open map from $X$ to $Y$. Show that then $f \in \mathcal{B}(X,Y).$

Here I denoted the set of all linear mappings from $X$ to $Y$ by $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$, and the set of all bounded mappings from $X$ to $Y$ by $\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$.
Does anyone have an idea about this statement? I appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Using given conditions, show that $f$ is also surjective. Then appeal to the inverse mapping theorem.

Comment: Can you help me to show that $f$ is surjective? I do not see it right away

Comment: Well, $f$ being surjective follows from openness. See how an open set looks like in Banach spaces.

Comment: Ah after spending some time I see this. So with the fact that $f$ is surjective then its inverse $f^{-1}$ is bounded?

Comment: Actually, since $f$ is open, $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Comment: So then by the inverse mapping theorem,  $f^{-1}$ since bijective and continuous linear map it will have a bounded inverse i.e. $f$ will be bounded?

Comment: You can complete the proof using inverse mapping theorem: since $f^{-1}$ is bounded linear, it follows $(f^{-1})^{-1}= f$ is also bounded linear!